# Argument "xyz" to "ABC" has incompatible type "Tuple[None, ...]"; expected "Tuple[None]"

Tags: mypy, python-typing

As an experiment, I wanted to add type annotations to my project and test it with `mypy --strict`. Consider the following code and the error message below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import typing as T


from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Question:
    choices: T.Tuple[None]


def gen_question() -> Question:

    choices = [None]

    return Question(choices=tuple(choices))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gen_question()
```

Here's the error message:

```
test.py:18: error: Argument "choices" to "Question" has incompatible type "Tuple[None, ...]"; expected "Tuple[None]"
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is that a bug? How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in case of typing.Tuple, according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple), if I need to specify a variable-length tuple I need to add `, ...` as in the following:

```
    choices: T.Tuple[None, ...]
```

Note that this doesn't seem to apply to lists.